# Custom Shapes with text in Android

Tags: android, shapes

I am new to android. I want to draw a custom shape in android. When someone chooses a date(via date picker) I want to display the result in a square box rather than the regular way.How do I achieve this?

Comment: Square box means text view or alert?

Comment: What is the "regular way?" Can you be more specific with what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am sorry for not being more specific. I couldnt add an image because I dont have some points :( I have a picture ready with me to show but I am unable to upload it

Comment: So here is what I want:
When the user chooses a date and time from the time picker the dialog closes and the date and time are displayed in text. Instead of that I want it build a custom UI design showing the date. Here is a link for the way i want it to be displayed https://www.dropbox.com/s/v7zd19ad5mjouvj/Date.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can use a textview to show the selected date. Since you seem to know the coding for that, I focus on the design you can apply for your textview.

By default, a textview has a rectangular shape with sharp edges and points, but you can achieve a rounded-corner textview using a style , like this one :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<stroke 
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/red"/>


<corners android:radius="7dp" />

<padding         
 android:left="1dp"
 android:right="1dp"
 android:top="1dp"
 android:bottom="1dp"/>

<solid android:color="@color/white"/></shape>
```

The corners tag, is responsible for the rounded corners, you can tweak th radius to make more or less rounded. 
Stroke tag, defines the width and color of the border for the textbox.
and Solid tag determines the bakcground color of the view.

In order to use this style, you should save it as an XML file and save it in drawable folder (normally drawable-hdpi will do). Then , in your tetxview or edittext you should set the background property as the following :

```
android:background="@drawable/thesavedxmlfile"
```